# Cannot understand the meaning of Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][-M, 2]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

When I do the following integration

```
Integrate[(Log[x]/x)*x^M*Exp[-x-1/x],{x,0,\[Infinity]},Assumptions->Element[M,PositiveIntegers]]
```

Mathematica return a very strange result that is

[image]

In this case what is the meaning of Derivative[1,0]. Is it some kind of dirac delta function ?

Comment: Would it help if you read it as $$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\nu}K_{\nu}(2)\right|_{\nu=-M}$$?

Comment: This is very strange, is there any way to obtain any numerical result from this expression ?

Comment: Have you already tried supplying a specific numerical value of `M`, and then using `N[]`?

Comment: [From the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html): "`Derivative[n1,n2,…][f]` is (...) a function obtained from `f` by differentiating `n1` times with respect to the first argument, `n2` times with respect to the second argument, and so on." which is what @J.M. wrote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For non-integer $M$ we can get an explicit expression for this derivative, as given on the [Wolfram Functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/20/01/01/):

```
f[M_] = Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][-M, 2] // FunctionExpand
(*    huge result    *)

f[0.37]
(*    -0.0179285    *)

Plot[f[M], {M, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

For specific values of $M$ we can get explicit expressions for this derivative directly:

```
Table[Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][-M, 2], {M, 0, 7}] // FunctionExpand

(*    {0,
       -1/2 BesselK[0, 2],
       -1/2 BesselK[0, 2] - BesselK[1, 2],
       -5/2 BesselK[0, 2] - 3 BesselK[1, 2],
       -10 BesselK[0, 2] - 13 BesselK[1, 2],
       -99/2 BesselK[0, 2] - 65 BesselK[1, 2],
       -575/2 BesselK[0, 2] - 381 BesselK[1, 2],
       -3863/2 BesselK[0, 2] - 2576 BesselK[1, 2]}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am interested in the case of integer M :) Particularly for M = 1,2,3,4....

Comment: Is there any way to add the assumption that M is a positive integer into the command Derivative[1, 0][BesselK][-M, 2] ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I don't know how to do it directly in Mathematica, but there's a formula on the [Wolfram Functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/20/01/01/0004/) that can be simplified to your `f[M_Integer?NonNegative] := -Sum[M!/(2*k!*(M-k))*BesselK[k,2], {k, 0, M-1}] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: Oh this is so nice thank you !